# .htacces without trailing slash redirect to with trailing slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using this .htaccess with this inside:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
DirectorySlash On

Options -Indexes

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.+)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(page1|page2|page3)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]

#Show every html,htm and xml as php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.xml$ $1.php [nc]
```

but i did not get to redirect http://example.com/page1  to -> http://example.com/page1/ (and the others page2 and page3 ). since i have test in local my url will be 
     localhost/example/page1 
and should redirect to 
     localhost/example/page1/ 
 does any one see any problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding a trailing slash you can have your rules like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
DirectorySlash On

Options -Indexes    
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1/ [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(page1|page2|page3)$ /$1/ [R=301,L,NC]

#Show every html,htm and xml as php
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.(?:xml|html?)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Still not working, did i have to scape after the first dot in RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC] ?  and what's NE and NC stand for?  also !-d is all recursively directories ? fyi i'm testing in my localhost

Comment: i'm entering http://localhost/example/page1 (and the other) and give me ERROR 301 - Moved Permanently

Comment: Why `/example/` in between, you didn't mention it any where? Where is .htaccess located inside `/example/`?

Comment: Is located in the root folder . In remote "http://example.com" and in local : "http://localhost/example/" in both cases should be HTTP_HOST equivalent isn't it?

Comment: No HTTP_HOST only contains `localhost`. Your .htaccess will vary if you are placing it in `/example/` folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51619/discussion-between-miguel-and-anubhava)